# How to save indirectly loaded images from webpages

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex

I know that most of the media in web pages are temporarily stored to a temp folder or browser cache. Some are directly embedded in web pages so that we can see the source and can save them. But how to save images loaded using any other method?

[You can see what I am talking about here](http://www.jayalakshmisilks.com/JayaLakshmi.html?department=Women). Is there any solution to save images from this site's gallery?

Comment: This website uses flash, not JS to load the images

Comment: @JochenJung is there any way to save images?? When we click gallery, there is an option to zoom.

Comment: Basically you want to save THOSE pictures? Nothing to do with javascript right?

Comment: @JochenJung is there any way to save THOSE images? Is there any software / tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a way to save the images by using the followings

1) Mozilla Firefox

2) Firebug

open the net console in it and select the tab named images

in that u can see all the images and save the images

for your reference, I attached a image.

[image]

then copy the location by right click and paste the location

and get the image.

~~~~~~ Happy Coding ~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: your answer is so informative and helpful. +1 for that. But you see, the images are in low resolution. It loads in original resolution only if you click an image and again if you click the zoom button on top. Is there any solution to save image in this original resolution?? Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: @blasteralfred That seems to be simple. clear the console before you click on zoom, it clears the previous request. now u ll see the image with large resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, js can't hold the image itself. but the Attribute src, a string instead. And js cannot handle the file on client, you can't modify, move, or copy files. So if you want to keep the images, you can send a http header like if-Modified-Since on server side with php or java, then the browser will not load the image again.

May this will help you. Good Luck!

Comment: thanks. But @trinity, I am a beginner. Can you give me a workaround??

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a offline browser.

They save whole webpages and deeping on software they catch more or less.

[Offline Browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offline_browser)

Comment: do you know any such tool saving the mentioned site?

Comment: I haven't been using one lately. Check tucows or download.com e.g. http://download.cnet.com/windows/offline-browsers/?tag=bc there is a whole bunch of them.